# Resident object in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I noticed that Controller object is creating each time when I call method in Controller class in ASP.NET MVC. So any  my object  existing only during  1 request. But other request will create another object. So I need to create object which will exist during Web site is running(Something like daemon). Is it possible to do such thing in one website without external services?

Comment: I mean not for all request 1 user(session), but for all requests all users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement through different ways.

1. Using Application object.
2. Putting the object in cache.
3. Use a singleton approach.

I personally suggest the last approach.